# How to make VSCode auto import work in a lerna-yarn-typescript project?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, lerna, yarn-workspaces

I have a lerna monorepo project with the following structure:

```
├─ packages
│    ├─ backend
│    │   ├─ package.json
│    │   ├─ tsconfig.json
│    │   └─ src
│    │      └─ index.ts
│    └─ shared
│        ├─ package.json
│        ├─ tsconfig.json
│        └─ src
│           └─ index.ts
├─ lerna.json
├─ package.json
├─ tsconfig.base.json
└─ tsconfig.json
```

I want to access interfaces declared in `shared` from the `backend` package.

`packages/shared/src/index.ts:`

```
export interface IPerson {
  name: string;
  doSomething: () => void;
}
```

But if I try to use the interface from the `backend` package vscode auto import won't show any suggestions.

`packages/backend/src/index.ts:`

[screenshot from VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGY54.png)

If I import it manually like : `import { IPerson } from '@example/shared/src/index';` it works like a charm.

Any ways to make VSCode recognise my shared project and suggest auto imports?

Here are the important files from the project:

`/tsconfig.json:`

```
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.base.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
      "baseUrl": "./packages",
      "paths": {
        "@example/backend": ["backend/src"],
        "@example/shared": ["shared/src"],
        "@example/*": ["*/src"]
      },
    },
    "references": [
      {
        "path": "./packages/backend"
      },
      {
        "path": "./packages/shared"
      }
    ]
  }
```

`/lerna.json:`

```
{
  "packages": [
    "packages/*"
  ],
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "npmClient": "yarn",
  "useWorkspaces": true
}
```

`/packages/backend/package.json:`

```
{
  "name": "@example/backend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@example/shared": "^0.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.9.0",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3"
  }
}
```

`/packages/backend/tsconfig.json:`

```
{
    "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
    "references": [
        { "path": "../shared" }
    ]
}
```

`/packages/shared/tsconfig.json:`

```
{
    "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "composite": true
    }
}
```

Thanks very much for any help!

Answer (score 0):

There's a setting
introduced in https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40637#issuecomment-717459902 to add a vscode setting `"project-relative"`

`.vscode/settings.json`

```
"typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier": "project-relative"
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
    "baseUrl": "./" /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */,
    "composite": true,
    "paths": {
      "@package-name/package-a": ["./packages/package-a/src"],
      "@package-name/package-b": ["./packages/package-b/src"]
    },
```